# NetLogo - Have one variable changed with a certain probability of a group of randomly chosen turtles

Tags: netlogo, probability

In `NetLogo`, I would like to have each round a likelihood of between 0 to 10 % turtles of the whole population to have a change of a variable. Within the chosen turtles, their variable can change between `+1` and `+4` by a certain likelihood.

```
breed [ humans human ]

humans-own [ var ]

to setup
  create-humans(population) [ set var 0 ]
end

to go
  ask humans [ var_change ]
end

to var_change [
let %draw (random-float 100)
     let %strength 0  ;no eco loss
     if (%draw < 50) [ set %strength (%strength + 1) ] ;1 little eco loss
     if (%draw < 10) [ set %strength (%strength + 2) ] ;2 middle eco loss
     if (%draw < 5) [ set %strength (%strength + 3) ] ;3 strong eco loss
     if (%draw < 1) [ set %strength (%strength + 4) ] ;4 complete eco loss
[ ask one-of %strength patches [ set economic economic + 3 ]]; here I do not know how to continue(*)
]
end
```

*I do not know how to code that between 0 to 10 % of turtles can have with a certain probability have their variable `var` changed. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it set up, all turtles are sent to the var_change procedure. It would be easier to have the var_change procedure both select the turtles to change and assign the amount of change. Something like:

```
to go
  var_change
end

to var_change
; choose proportion to change
let %draw-prop random-float 0.1
let n-changers round (%draw-prop * count turtles) + 1 ; +1 so at least one changes
; change by some amount
ask n-of n-changers turtles
[ let %draw-change random 100
  set economic economic + 1 ;all get some eco loss
  if (%draw-change < 10) [ set economic economic + 1 ] ;2 middle eco loss
  if (%draw-change < 5) [ set economic economic + 1] ;3 strong eco loss
  if (%draw-change < 1) [ set economic economic + 1 ] ;4 complete eco loss
]
end
```

Note that I changed all your + amounts to + 1. The way you had it written, drawing a number like 3 would have added 1 (as <50) then another 2 (as <10) then another 3 (as <5) for a total increase of 6. An `if` clause runs the code if the `if` condition is satisfied and skips over it if not satisfied. Either way, the next code always runs.